# Limit Rows in Result Set By Column Values

Tags: java, hibernate

This question deals with building a correct `Criteria` in Hibernate for the following case.

Suppose I start with a table like this:

```
id ts metric   value carrier
1  1  distance 4     alice
2  1  count    2     alice
3  2  distance 3     alice
4  2  count    1     alice
5  1  distance 3     becky
6  1  count    2     becky
7  2  distance 4     becky   
8  2  count    1     becky
9  1  distance 10    other
10 1  count    10    other
11 2  distance 10    other
12 2  distance 10    other
```

What this is is a time-bucketed set of metrics recording how far `alice`, `becky` and a general `other` carried some `count` of items some `distance`.

I'd like to roll it up in the following fashion: metrics with 'other' or the 'winner' as decided by `distance` for each time bucket are kept. Thus, the above table would yield the following result set:

```
id ts metric   value carrier
1  1  distance 4     alice
2  1  count    2     alice
7  2  distance 4     becky   
8  2  count    1     becky
9  1  distance 10    other
10 1  count    10    other
11 2  distance 10    other
12 2  distance 10    other
```

Ultimately this is translated to this:

```
ts carrier distance count
1  alice   4        2
1  other   10       10
2  becky   4        1
2  other   10       10
```

But this translation I already understand how to do. What I'm unclear on is how to build the criteria to keep the 'top n' metrics. Which brings us to the wrinkle: while this example is simplified, there would be a large number of 'carriers', and what I'm interested in is the top `n` such carriers, discarding the rest. Thus in the example above `n = 1`, but it's likely to be greater than `1` in most cases.

I know that I can use `addOrder(Order.desc("value")`, but that poses both a problem in that `other` is intermixed *and* distances and counts will be incorrectly intermingled. I'm looking for something that sorts 'blocks' of rows which are decided, in order by `ts`, then `carrier`, then using the `metric = "distance"` for the sort order.

Comment: This looks like something I would use [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) for if I was working with SQL in Postgres, but Hibernate might not be as readily equipped for such things.

Comment: @Kayaman Possibly, but I couldn't find any direct support for that in Hibernate.

Comment: That's what I meant. Database specific extensions are unlikely to be supported in Hibernate, so I'm doubting very much about criteria API being able to do what you want. If you can come up with *standard* SQL to do the above things, that would be a whole different beast.